# Deploying Python Flask API on Apache on Windows 7

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to deploy my `Python Flask API` using `Apache` on Windows 7. I found that since Python is not a native development language it needs `WSGI (Web Service Gateway Interface)` to connect to Apache. I also found some tutorials on that but none of them did work for me:

1- [Running a Flask application under the Apache WSGI module](http://www.jakowicz.com/flask-apache-wsgi/)

For this tutorial when I run `sudo a2ensite my.webtool` I get an error message that says that `a2ensite` is not an internal or external command.

2- [mod_wsgi (Apache)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/)

And for this one, I followed all the steps. I have only changed the `ServerName` in:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:\yourdir\yourapp.wsgi
    <Directory C:\yourdir>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So instead of `example.com` I put `my-flask`, and of course I changed the paths to my application and saved that in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. Then I added this line in the `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 my-flask
```

And finally in `httpd.conf` file I removed the `#` from this line:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The problem is when I restarted Apache Server, it did not start and I got an Error that says: `The requested operation has failed!`

**[UPDATE]**

`my-flask.wsgi` file looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/Cybula-EDF/Documents/Flask/prod')
from my-flask import app as application
```

This is what `LoadModule` says:

```
> mod_wsgi-express module-config
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi-4.5.14-py2.7-win-amd64.egg/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgiNone"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python27"
```

This is what I have under `c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi-4.5.14-py2.7-win-amd64.egg/mod_wsgi/server/` :

```
   Name           |      Type
  ----------------------------------------------
  management      |     (File folder)
  __init__        |     (Python File)
  __init__        |     (Compiled Python File)
  apxs_config     |     (Python File)
  apxs_config     |     (Compiled Python File)
  environ         |     (Python File)
  environ         |     (Compiled Python File)
  mod_wsgi        |     (Python File)
  mod_wsgi        |     (Compiled Python File)
  mod_wsgi        |     (Python Extension Module) 
  -----------------------------------------------
```

The Python Extension Module `mod_wsgi` has `.pyd` as extension.

3- [Using Apache and Python WSGI on Windows](https://www.devbattles.com/en/sand/post-304-using+Apache+and+Python+WSGI+on+Windows)

When I followed this one, the Apache Server worked fine but when I typed:

```
localhost/hello_world.wsgi
```

It didn't show `Hello World!`, but instead it showed a page with an error that says the page couldn't be found.

Please can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? maybe I missed some details or something. Thanks!

Comment: How did you actually install mod_wsgi for a start. None of those links that I can see show the preferred way of getting the module installed.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Using that link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi  . And I followed this link to install Apache: http://documentation.veremes.net/public/ressource/apache_httpd_guide_installation.pdf

Comment: In the ``VirtualHost``, use ``*:80``, not just ``*``. Without the port it doesn't know what port it is supposed to be applied to. Also don't use backslashes in path in Apache. Preferably use foward slashes.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton There is something weird, I cannot find `mod_wsgi` in `C:\Apache24\modules` . I thought once installed I could find it in the `modules` folder.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I did what you suggested but still have the same error. Please see the UPDATE, I forgot to mention the code of `my-flask.wsgi`

Comment: What does your ``LoadModule`` line for mod_wsgi say. If you use the ``pip install`` method and then used ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to work out what configuration to add to the Apache configuration to load mod_wsgi, there should actually have been three lines to add. One with ``LoadFile``, one with ``LoadModule`` and one with ``WSGIPythonHome``. Did you even use ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to display config to use and add it to the Apache config file?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Please check again the update part

Comment: What is in the directory ``c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi-4.5.14-py2.7-win-amd64.egg/mod_wsgi/server``. You are hitting an issue where the extension doesn't get added properly and instead shows ``None``. You need to work out what actual name of mod_wsgi module is in that directory. Usually has ``.pyd`` or ``.pyo`` extension. For the people hitting this, never been able to get enough help from anyone to get the code fixed to generate correct extension.

Comment: Trying to resolve this in SO comments is a pain. Should use mod_wsgi mailing list instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145962/discussion-between-benz-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: Sorry, I don't use SO chat. That is what the mod_wsgi mailing list is for.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton What is mod_wsgi mailing list?

Comment: See mod_wsgi documentation. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/finding-help.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I guess it was because of Python's version `Python 2.7`. I used `Anaconda3` now with `Python 3.6`, installed `mod_wsgi` using `pip` and I don't have that error anymore. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I know it is only Anaconda 2.7. Have been trying to get someone to help me resolve it and get a fix added a couple of times now but been unsuccessful.